# Finding the inverse function of $\frac{x}{ \sqrt{1+x^2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by $f(x)=\frac{x}{ \sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

Before I have tried to find the $f^{-1}$, I determinated the range of $f$ that will be the domain of $f^{-1}$.
The range of $f$ is $]-1,1[$.

To find $f^{-1}$ my work was:

$$y=\frac{x}{ \sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

It's known that $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ it's allways positive. If $\space y \in ]-1,1[$ then the sign of $y$ depends of $x$ (numerator). So $x$ and $y$ have the same sign and then I can squared both, $y$ and $x$, without any problem.

$$y^2=\left( \frac{x}{ \sqrt{1+x^2}} \right)^2\Leftrightarrow$$

$$y^2=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2} \Leftrightarrow$$

$$y^2 (1+x^2)=x^2 \Leftrightarrow$$

$$y^2 +y^2x^2=x^2 \Leftrightarrow y^2=x^2- y^2x^2 \Leftrightarrow y^2=x^2 (1- y^2) \Leftrightarrow$$
$$x^2=\frac{y^2}{1- y^2} $$

Now squaring both parts and because $x$ and $y$ have the same sign,$$x=\frac{y}{\sqrt{1- y^2}}$$

So $f^{-1}(y)=\frac{y}{\sqrt{1- y^2}}$. Is this right? Thanks

Comment: We must prove $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$ for this to be true.
$$\frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}{\sqrt{1 - (\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}})^2}} = x$$

Comment: At first glance, this looks correct to me - the 'walk through the algebra' is exactly what you want to do.

Comment: The algebra is correct. However there is one small issue that is bothering me. For a function to have an inverse, it must be one-one and onto. IN the problem the domain and range of the function is $\mathbb R$ . If y=1, x is undefined. Hence the function cannot be onto and inverse shouldn't exist in the given domain and range right?

Comment: @GTXOC : Is that a question or a doubt?

Comment: @GTXOC: it is easy to see that $1$ is not in the range of $f$: $f(x)=1$ implies $x=\sqrt{1+x^2}$, which in turn implies $0=1$.

Comment: @GTXOC when I wrote $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ I meant that $\mathbb{R}$ is the domain and codomain of $f$. This function is not onto because the codomain is not equal to the range. But it's one-to-one. I previous found the derivative of $f$ and conclued that is always positive. So $f$ is always rising and then is one-to-one. To have inverse, a function only needs to be one-to-one.